# Access State in the Constructor?

Tags: reactjs

How can I access a state in the constructor?

For context, when using 'this.state.count' in the constructor, I receive the error: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined'.

Comment: Please review [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example.

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to define your state in constructor first.

**BAD**:

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  console.log(this.state.count) // ERROR - state is undefined
}
```

**GOOD**

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {count: 1};
  console.log(this.state.count) // state is defined by this.state = {count: 1};
}
```